# Convert cmd to powershell

Tags: powershell, cmd

How can I convert this cmd to powershell

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Image Instruments\abcClient
“XYZ.exe” -PatId=”11111” -Firstname=“John” -Lastname=“Do” -Birthday=”19971101” -Sex=“M” -City=“Frankfurt”
```

I tried something like this, but does not work. It opens the .exe without arguments:

```
$pathExe = Set-Location “C:\Program Files (x86)\Image Instruments\abcClient”
$openExe = Start-Process “XYZ.exe”
$PatId = ”11111”
$Firstname = “John”
$Lastname = “Doe”
$Birthday = ”19971101”
$Sex = “M”
$City = “Frankfurt”
$pathExe; & $openExe@('-PatID='+$PatId, '-Firstname=’+$Firstname, '-Lastname='+$Lastname, ’-Birthday=’+$Birthday, ‘-Sex=’+$Sex, '-City='+$City)
```

As I have no experience with programming, how I could bring this to work?

Thank you for any advice

Comment: When you do get proficient in PowerShell, look into the PowerShell module [Crescendo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/crescendo/overview?view=ps-modules) for wrapping legacy commands into PowerShell cmdlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like cmd, PowerShell is a shell that supports invoking programs directly, with arguments.

Therefore, your command looks very similar in PowerShell:

```
Set-Location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Image Instruments\abcClient"
XYZ.exe -PatId="11111" -Firstname="John" -Lastname="Do" -Birthday="19971101" -Sex="M" -City="Frankfurt"
```

- The equivalent of `cd` in PowerShell is `Set-Location` (although `cd` works too, because it is defined as an *alias* for it).
- Note the need to *quote*, the target directory passed to `Set-Location`, given that its path contains spaces.
- *Unquoted* use of `XYZ.exe` allows its direct invocation; if you quote the program name (e.g., as `"XYZ.exe"`), you would have to prepend `&` , the call operator.
- If you want to use *variables* in your arguments, simply use them in lieu of the literal strings; e.g. `-PatId="11111"` can be replaced with `-PatId="$PatId"`, assuming that you've defined `$PatId = "11111"` beforehand.
- Though they do not come into play here, there *are* differences between cmd and PowerShell with respect to what characters need quoting when you pass arguments and how special characters are escaped - see [`Get-Help about_parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1)
- If `XYZ.exe` is a *console* application (which appears to be the case), PowerShell will execute it *synchronously* - that is, PowerShell will wait until the application has exited and will reflect its exit code in automatic variable `$LASTEXITCODE`.

Comment: I tried this and is working well. But if I replace -PatId="11111" with -PatId=$PatId, which I defined before $PatId = ”11111”, it passes "$PatId" and not"11111". What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I found it: I have to take -PatId="$PatId" in my case. Nevertheless, thanks a lot for showing me the wright way.

Comment: @KoLa: Glad to hear it; thanks for pointing out the need to enclose `$PatId` in `"..."` in `-PatId="$patId"` - I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Get / Convert / Access / Translate Cmd COMMAND Variables in PowerShell:

You may want to try the following which I have 'found' works in a single PC environment:

```
#- Set up Cmd Variable -----
$zCmdVariable = "%UserProfile%"
#- Get Contents from Cmd -----
$zConvertedVariable = (cmd /c "echo $zCmdVariable")
#- Use contents in Powershell -----
Get-Item -Path $zConvertedVariable
```

I hope this helps; Pass It forward.

Answer (score -1):

So, the ProcessStartInfo object defines parameters to pass into a process:

FileName - This is what you'll be executing

WorkingDirectory - The execution path that it will be running from (not always the same as the file's directory but often is). Important if you have things like relative paths

Arguments - This is what is getting passed as the process arguments.

```
$startInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$startInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Image Instruments\abcClient\XYZ.exe"
$startInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Image Instruments\abcClient\"
$startInfo.Arguments = "-PatId=11111 -Firstname=John -Lastname=Do -Birthday=19971101 -Sex=M -City=Frankfurt"
```

Then you start a process object, and wait for it to complete.

```
$process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
$process.StartInfo = $startInfo
$process.Start()
$process.WaitForExit()
```

Then get it's return code (usually EXEs with a 0 mean success).

```
$exitCode = $process.ExitCode
```

Comment: It is working like a charm. Thanks so much.
Why I do need the expression "System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"

Comment: Powershell can call .net code...system.diagnostics is the namespace containing process and processstartinfo...if u like...can u please "accept" the answer...on screen option...thanks...glad to help